# GWT : Sound not playing mobile?

Tags: html, gwt, audio

i tryed the gwt - voices libary and Audio.
But both didnt work... they work on my Pc but not with my mobile browser:

https://gwt-voices.appspot.com/demo/VoicesDemo.html <-- the mp3 example here works fine with my Mobile browswer , what am i doing wrong?

```
                   SoundController soundController2 = new SoundController();
                    final Sound sound2 = soundController2.createSound(Sound.MIME_TYPE_AUDIO_MPEG_MP3,
                        "Powerup.mp3");


                    sound2.addEventHandler(new SoundHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPlaybackComplete(
                                PlaybackCompleteEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSoundLoadStateChange(
                                SoundLoadStateChangeEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if(event.getLoadState().toString().equals("LOAD_STATE_SUPPORTED_AND_READY")){
                                sound2.play();
                            }

                        }

                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, mobile Safari only enables sound if a sound is played as a reaction to a user event. So you may want to play some sound as a reaction to some touch event to enable sounds.